# Can I enable format warnings for my custom logging function?

Tags: c, mingw, compiler-warnings

For debugging purposes, I've created a custom logging function. For all practical purposes, let's say it's defined like this:

```
void debugLog(const char * s, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, s);
    if(NULL!=logfp) {
        vfprintf(logfp, s, args);
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

The problem is that format warnings are skipped for my custom function.

If I write, for example:

```
fprintf(logfp, "Received error: %d.\n");
```

I'll get a warning like this:

> warning: format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat]

But I won't get any warning if I call:

```
debugLog("Received error: %d.\n");
```

## Is there a way to enable such a warning for my function?

Maybe I can tell mingw-gcc to treat debugLog the way it would treat printf?
Or are this kind of warnings hard-coded into the compiler? (ie: gcc simply *knows* the *printf* family but we can't expect it to know my function)

Comment: Answer can be found in this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825270/printflike-modifier

Comment: Thanks @SteveSummit, that Q also lead me to this related question for MSVC: [__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2))) for MSVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354784/attribute-formatprintf-1-2-for-msvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least with gcc, you can use the [function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html):

```
__attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)))
void debugLog(const char * s, ...) {
    ...
}
```